# What is "a crown of raging shadow" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Excerpt from *Her Lover (Belle de Seigneur)* by *Albert Cohen*

> Leaning bare-chested over the open case, he took out an old tattered greatcoat and a moth-eaten fur hat and stared in surprise at the tie of the Order which his searching hand had found. It was crimson and very handsome. Might as well put it on since it was there. When he had tied it around his neck, he struck a pose before the swing-mirror. Oh yes, disgustingly handsome. An impassible face beneath **a crown of raging shadow**. Narrow hips, flat stomach, broad chest and, under the tanned skin, muscles like intertwining serpents.

What is "a crown of raging shadow" in this context?

In dictionary it says "the crown of something" means the top part of something, but "beneath a top of raging shadow" doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think it's probably not a very good translation (I'm pretty sure that should be [*An **impassive** face*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=impassible+face%2Cimpassive+face&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)). But it's highly metaphoric language anyway, so the *exact* meaning is subjective.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about the meaning of a literary translation. That should be answered by reference to the original French, which is obviously Off Topic here.

Comment: ha ha: his searching hand had found. What a hoot. Then, it says: it was crimson and very handsome. What a poorly done translation. You need to provide a link, if  you have one. This sounds like it's all about *le droit de cuissage*.

Comment: ***David Coward** is Research Professor in French at the University of Leeds. He has written widely on the literature and culture of France since 1700 and has translated tales by Sade and Maupassant, plays by Moliere and novels by Diderot and Dumas fils. [**His English version of Albert Cohen's Belle du Seigneur was awarded the Scott-Moncrieff Prize for Translation in 1996.***](https://www.wob.com/en-gb/books/author/david-coward) Which makes that ***impassive / impassible face*** issue all the more weird - unless it's simply been mis-copied here.

Comment: ...I imagine OP's highlighted item is just a poetic / literary figurative way of referring to [his "cool / dashing / foppish" thick hair.](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/cool-wavy-long-medium-hair-men--390265123949219151/)

Comment: CYC - this question will probably get closed anyway, but if you could at least tell us ***who translated*** the version you're working with, you might still get a "definitive" answer. I find it hard to believe the text as cited here would win any awards, but I might give it more serious consideration if I knew it was definitely Coward's work, accurately transcribed. If it was someone else, though, perhaps ***raging*** was a bungled attempt to convey something like ***stylish / fashionable = "all the rage"***.

Comment: A surprising number of Google Books hits for the phrase [***face beneath a crown of***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22face+beneath+a+crown+of%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALiCzsaQZtn6xwudvuNp-W-JnBmdjWuppQ:1669518800605&ei=0NWCY-XIJPXP7_UPx86BkA8&start=0&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjl8LiYss37AhX157sIHUdnAPI4KBDy0wN6BAgKEAc&biw=1129&bih=633&dpr=2.5) But none that match up with yours. I think you found a bad copy/transcription online.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is supposed to be the David Coward version though I can't verify its authenticity. The following content of Belle de Seigneur(the excerpt is on the bottom left) is screen captured from Internet Archive: https://i.imgur.com/ixw1n8s.png

Comment: Thanks for posting that link. I had assumed **impassible** was incorrect (or just "alternative") spelling for **impassable**. But checking the *full* (subscription-only) Oxford English Dictionary I find this definition 3 for **impassible** *- Incapable of feeling or emotion; **impassive**, insensible, unimpressible....*

Comment: ... I'm still not convinced it was a wise choice, considering *Belle du Seigneur* was written in 1968, whereas the OED's most recent citation for that [never-very-common term](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=impassible%2Cimpassable&year_start=1850&year_end=1980&corpus=26&smoothing=3) was way back in 1876. But it's "valid". As for your *actual* question, about the "crown of raging shadow", I find no relevant "peculiar" meaning for ***raging*** in OED, so I'm at a bit of a loss there. I don't have access to the original French, but maybe someone else will help on that front.

Answer (score -1):

"Crown" can mean the top of something, so when speaking of someone's head or face it means the top of the forehead or the forehead in general. So here, he's saying something about the look of his face beneath a certain look of his forehead.

This is an awkward translation. "Impassible" means something that you cannot get past, like "A tree fell on the road making the road impassible." I don't know what an "impassible face" would mean. The intent was probably "impassive face", meaning a face that shows no emotion.

Likewise, a crown or forehead "of raging shadows", well, apparently the writer is trying to be poetic, but it's not clear to me what that means. Maybe that his forehead displays strong emotions ("raging") while his face shows none?

Comment: It's nothing to do with ***impassable*** - incapable of being traversed. It's ***impassible*** - uncommon / dated / literary term semantically overlapping with ***impassive***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're right. I concede the point. I was unfamiliar with the word and jumped to a wrong conclusion.

Comment: I didn't know the word "impassible" myself, so I originally made the same mistake about that, *and* compounded things with my initial "probably not a very good translation" comment under the question. Having since discovered that *this particular translation* is well-regarded (and OP has accurately transcribed it), I feel compelled to assume ***crown of raging shadow*** must have some meaning / "literary merit". Now I'm really intrigued, so I do hope someone with access to the original French can help us dig a little deeper here.